# Vue-router cannot lazy load child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, lazy-loading, vue-router

I'm using vue-router inside my project, which is working with a library that is, unfortunately, not in active development anymore. I needed to add a few things there, so I downloaded the source, edited it myself and then built it into my project's "externals" folder.

Now, until the project was not using front-end router everything worked fine, but lately, I implemented the vue-router with lazy-loading components and things got a bit trickier.

Library I was talking about is saved inside `@/externals/date-picker`.
Inside my lazy-loaded component I import it using es6 imports:

```
import DatePicker from '@/externals/date-picker';
```

Which triggers an error inside `vue-router`:

> Failed to resolve async component default: TypeError: Cannot set property 'vue-date-picker' of undefined

I have no idea what's going on, but it seems like it cannot add the date-picker to `module.exports`.

I'm pretty sure there has to be the way to load external files even though they're lazy loaded. So, my question is, how can I add the external file/package to my lazy-loaded component? Thank you in advance.

**CODE**

```
// router.js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/something',
            name: 'something',
            title: 'something',
            component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "something" */ './views/Component.vue')
        }
    ]
});

// Component.vue
<script>
    import DatePickerOriginal from "@/external/date-picker";

    export default {
        components: {
            DatePickerOriginal
        }
    };
</script>
```

And the source code of `@/external/date-picker` is almost the same as [here](https://github.com/ridewn/vue-date-picker/blob/master/dist/vue-date-picker.min.js) (well, the build tooling was the same, and the application itself most likely does not cause the problem). Also, it might be nice to point out once again, the application is not in the `node_modules` folder with other packages, but is loaded from `@/externals/date-picker`.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking about. However lazy loading is about webpack and you can do it by: `() => import something from somewhere`

Comment: Can you please add some code? If you have a library it can be imported from node-modules for example moment.js: `import moment from 'moment'`

Comment: @roliroli sure, thanks for interest. The question is updated. All relevant code is there I guess.

Comment: it seems to me like the package is not built correctly, but I'm not sure what can I do to fix this. I was building it without changing anything, but the `output.path`. Configurationn can be found [here](https://github.com/ridewn/vue-date-picker).

Comment: So the DatePickerOriginal is a component? Can you show some code from it?

Comment: Also just to be sure add vue extention like `@/external/date-picker.vue`

Comment: I've just tried lots of combinations. It seems that the files cannot be loaded from `@/external/date-picker` if I put the same file into the `node_module`'s loading works fine. Weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I was missing `libraryTarget: 'window'` in my webpack config, while merging the package in build process.

```
merge(commonConfig, {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname + '/src/plugin.js'),
    output: {
        // ...
        libraryTarget: 'window'
    }
})
```